# Service Stack 6 UI

Tags: c#, servicestack

I recently upgraded to ServiceStack 6 and trying to get the API UI to work. I have 2 issues.
After I authenticate (I have custom CredentialsAuthProviderSync) I still get an error that I need to authenticate (requires Authentication)

I then took out authentication for a service to test without Authentication and I get the below error.
Unexpected token E in JSON at position 0.
The browser log shows: Couldn't find Request DTO for ...

Comment: This doesn't provide enough info to repro the issue, you can try updating to [v6.0.3 on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget) to get the latest version to check if it's already been resolved. If it's still an issue, you can post a stand-alone repro on GitHub and I'll be able to investigate further.

Comment: I am currently on 6.0.3. In terms of code this is a large project what would you need in terms of code?

Comment: If you're already on v6.0.3 [clear your NuGet packages cache](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget#clear-nuget-package-cache) and restore again to get the latest v6.0.3. Otherwise I will need a stand-alone repro, I can't resolve issues I can't reproduce.

Comment: In addition, I don't actually have to use API UI, can we still use OpenAPI or Swagger? My team have become used to Swagger and this is still our preferred API explorer

Comment: Sure, you can continue using [Open API](https://docs.servicestack.net/openapi) with /swagger-ui.

Comment: Thx, got Swagger going, a few minor changes in regards to config of authenticating.